# Softlayer slcli command to create iscsi issue

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I can't create iscsi storage with the slcli command.

C:>slcli iscsi create --size 50 --datacenter wdc01
Could not find a valid price with for the given size

C:>slcli iscsi create --size 100 --datacenter wdc01
Could not find a valid price with for the given size

My package level is SoftLayer (5.0.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the ISCSI devices are not available anymore in Softlayer, they have been replaced by block storage (endurance and performance) and file storage (endurance and perfomance). Currently the SLCLI does not support order either block storage nor file storage.

Regards

Comment: Thank you that info but can I create block storage from the CLI?
My storage options are:

C:\>slcli  | findstr -i Storage
  iscsi           iSCSI storage.
  nas             Network Attached Storage.
  object-storage  Object Storage.

Network Attached storage storage seems to what I want. I don't see block
but it has no create options
C:\>slcli  nas
Usage: slcli nas [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Network Attached Storage.

Options:
  -h, --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  credentials  List NAS account credentials.
  list         List NAS accounts.

Comment: nop you cannot create block storage using the CLI, that feature is not implemented. You have to use api calls see https://softlayer.github.io/python/place_order_block_storage_performance_iscsi/